# Login user with HWIOAuthBundle in AJAX

Tags: ajax, facebook, symfony, authentication, hwioauthbundle

I'm implementing a page with a form on Symfony with a specific treatment. When user clicks on the button, a call in AJAX is sent to my server. When the user is not authenticated we put the information in the response and the client displays a login popup with Facebook Connect Link. All of this is OK. Now, if the user clicks on the Facebook Connect Link, I have implemented [this](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/bonus/facebook-connect.md#user-content-adding-the-facebook-login-button).
My problem is that if the user is logged in Facebook, this code does a redirection with this:

```
document.location = "{{ url("hwi_oauth_service_redirect", {service: "facebook"}) }}";
```

I'd like to replace this code with a call in AJAX to authenticate the user in the server, then get the response and if the response is OK then submit my form again.
How i can do this ?

I have developed a handler to return the response in JSON with onAuthenticationSuccess and onAuthenticationFailure function. There is no problem in this part. So my problem is before.

In fact, I'd like a behavior like the "List Your Space" page of Airbnb site. See [here](https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/new?locale=en).

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED:**

Like I said in my comment, in an oauth architecture, the user must be redirected to the authentifier (here facebook) to authenticate and/or authorize your application to access his user data. You won't be able to do it in ajax because you cannot request another domain because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). However, you can take a look at 2 solutions:

**CORS:**

You can try using CORS but you may lose some security in the process (and I do not know if facebook allows it).

**Iframe:**

You can try to create an iframe in javascript with the facebook authentication page but this will be hard to achieve and work with it!

**Bonus:**

You may decide to deal with the redirection but give the real url the user was before being redirected in order him back on after his login. To do that, you can override the action `redirectToServiceAction` of the controller `HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Controller\ConnectController` to pass the current url:

```
public function redirectToServiceAction(Request $request, $service)
{
    $redirectUri = $request->query->get('redirect_uri');

    // ...

    return new RedirectResponse($this->container->get('hwi_oauth.security.oauth_utils')->getAuthorizationUrl($request, $service, $redirectUri));
}
```

Then you need to modify your javascript:

```
document.location =
    '{{ url("your_oauth_service_redirect", {service: "facebook"}) }}' +
    '&redirect_uri=' +
    document.location
;
```

Comment: Thank you but your solution does not work. I have tried it with JQuery and I have debugged the code. The AJAX Query calls ConnectController.redirectToServiceAction but I think the problem is that this function return a Redirect Response and with AJAX it does not work. Have you tried and checked your solution ? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Oh yes I told you some b... s...! In an oauth architecture, the user must be redirected to the authentifier (here facebook) to authenticate and/or authorize your application to access his user data. You won't be able to do it in ajax because you cannot request another domain. You can try using [CORS](http://devcenter.kinvey.com/html5/tutorials/how-to-implement-safe-signin-via-oauth#OAuthandJavaScript) but you will lose some security in the process (and I do not know if facebook allows it). I will change my answer tomorrow in order to give you a better explanation of why it is not possible.

Comment: I tried your last bonus solution. I had no errors but my problem is that I don't know how to post my form. In fact, I found a website which do the result I'd like. See here https://www.airbnb.fr/rooms/new. Please, can you give us a solution with the same behavior and workflow ? I edited and improved my question with this.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot help you to study that code. It takes too much time.  You should take a look at the [RFC for oauth2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749) to understand what you can do and how.

Answer (score 0):

add into config.yml, under hwi_oauth:

target_path_parameter: _destination

then, build link like that in twig :

```
<a href="{{ path('hwi_oauth_service_redirect', { 'service': 'myservice', '_destination' : app.request.requestUri }) }}" class="connect">
```